# How can I recover my SD card?

Tags: sd-card

Is there a way to recover my SD card (for free)? I get a message that says it has been corrupted. Simply formatting it again hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SD Card Formatter on a PC? It seems the best way to format a SD Card, however if formatting in Android doesn't works I think it's pretty much dead.
But as I said, try SD Card Formatter to see if that helps.
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/